# jquery find text and change size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-size, contains

I have a грн text in a div "price" with a span class "price-red"

```
    <div class="price">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td width="190"><span class="price-text">Цена для вас:</span></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" height="10"></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td><nobr><span class="price-red"><b>299 грн.</b></span></nobr></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

css

```
.price-red{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 60px;
text-transform: none;
```

}

I need to find it with jquery and change font from 60px to 40px only for "грн"
So I tried this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.price-red:contains("грн")').css('font-size', '40px');
});
</script>
```

Text **299 грн.** is generated by php like this:

```
<td><?php if (!empty($special)){ ?><span class="price-red">Sale!</span><?php }else{ ?><nobr><span class="price-red"><b><?php echo $price; ?></b></span></nobr><?php } ?></td>
    <td><?php if (!empty($special)){ ?><span class="price-red"><b><?php echo $special; ?></b></span><?php } ?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$('span.price-red:contains("грн")').html(function () {
    return this.innerHTML.replace("грн", "<span style='font-size:40px'>грн</span>")
});
});
```

Comment: $('span.price-red div:contains("грн")').css('font-size', '40px');

Comment: It works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/JZUR3/2/

Comment: Your fiddle works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to change rph you can do this with html() and wrap rph with a span

```
$('span.price-red:contains("грн")').html(function () {
    return this.innerHTML.replace("грн", "<span style='background:blue;font-size:40px;'>грн</span>")
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/JZUR3/4/)

Comment: He did not ask to change only "грн" he wanted to change all span style.

Comment: @ShlomiHassid in his question he wrote >>I need to find it with jquery and change font from 60px to 40px only for "грн" So I tried this:

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. The problem might be **character encoding**. If your jQuery code and HTML are placed in different files they might have different encoding.
To test it, try replace the span content with some standard letters, like "rph" and see if `:contains` selector works with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.price span.price-red:contains("грн")').css('font-size', '40px');
});
```

reference **[contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**

Comment: Thank!It's working but it's changing the whole price not just "грн"

Comment: @user1429497 You can't change the font-size of the textNodes, you shold wrap the text with another element and style that instead.